# How to get response using Kendo file upload async method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-upload

I am using kendo to upload files from the client everything is working as expected while loading , But here i have question related to url when we upload files i am using url in the config when file loads succesfully i have response from the server.

How can i extract data from response using kendo async saveUrl method ?

main.html

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="prcFileUploadField">File:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input name="file" type="file" kendo-upload="fileAttachment" k-upload="addMorePostParameters" k-success="onSuccess" k-error="onError" k-options="fileAttachmentOptions" k-select="onSelect" k-remove="onUploadRemove" />
    </div>
</div>
```

ctrl.js

```
angular.module('App').controller('PrcUploadCtrl',function($scope,$timeout,$rootScope,prcUploadConfig){
    'use strict';
    var fileData = [];
    $scope.fileAttachmentOptions = prcUploadConfig.fileAttachmentConfig;

    $scope.prcUploadGridOptions = prcUploadConfig.getPrcUploadDataGrid;
    prcUploadConfig.getPrcUploadDataGrid.dataSource='';

    $scope.onSelect = function (e) {
        fileData = e.files;
        var message = $.map(e.files, function(file) { return file.name; }).join(", ");
        console.log(message);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(fileData));
    };

    //if error 
    $scope.onError = function() {
        console.log("loggin error");
        $timeout(function () {
            var filesToBeRemoved = $scope.fileAttachment.wrapper.find('.k-file');
            $scope.fileAttachment._removeFileEntry(filesToBeRemoved);
        },5000);
    }
});
```

config.js

```
fileAttachmentConfig: {
  async: {
      saveUrl: 'app/upload/uploadAttch',
      removeUrl: 'remove',
      removeVerb: 'DELETE',
      autoUpload: false
  },
  template: '<span class=\'file-name-heading\'>Name:</span> <span>#=name#</span><button type=\'button\' class=\'k-upload-action\'></button>'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always get a response body from successful requests like this:

```
$scope.onSuccess = function(e) {
    var response = e.response;
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer i can see response now.